# Google_auth JSON key with Heroku config var?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, google-api, credentials

To make a server-server interact with a Google API in development I need to put my service-account JSON key in the root of myapp, set

```
ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "api-test-key.json"
```

and all is good.

But in production on Heroku there are config vars and the google_auth [credentials_loader.rb](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/master/lib/googleauth/credentials_loader.rb) insists on a file.

I managed to put the JSON's contents in a heroku config var nicely and can get it by calling

```
puts ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
```

What to do?

There is this question where they figured out a workaround but that is for oauth2 not for service-account type JSON:

[How to upload a json file with secret keys to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144135/how-to-upload-a-json-file-with-secret-keys-to-heroku#)

Answer (score 0):

We config our GoogleAPI credentials via the application.yml file ... found in the root/config/application.yml file.

In it we have;

```
AUTH_URI: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
CLIENT_SECRET: xxxxxxx
TOKEN_URI: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
CLIENT_EMAIL: xxxx
REDIRECT_URIS: http://localhost:3000/signin/connect
CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/901506026811-q0am03i585627ptu5r38o7cpkt8pk98l@developer.gserviceaccount.com
CLIENT_ID: xxx
AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
JAVASCRIPT_ORIGINS: http://localhost:3000
PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read
```

You could maybe load in your config settings here?

Comment: Thanks but it is for oauth2. BTW is it checked in to version control?

Comment: Yes it is - you're right most people keep such a file on .gitignore ... as loaded in separately.  

Maybe you have no file in version control?